# HTML not reacting to CSS changes

Tags: html, css, xampp

This has never happened to me
I started to use XAMMP a few days ago and it started happening. Last time I had to erase the CSS file I had and create a new one, it worked but now it happened again. Every change I make is not detected by the HTML

Here are some photos of the problem
[The web shows old code while the Visual Code shows how I want it to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0ibU.png)

[And everything is saved, so it's not like I forgot to Save the code before running it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2VZE.png)

[Also the route is exactly as it is on the files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GLEgQ.png)

Inspecting element doesn't show that it had a problem reaching the CSS, but also doesn't react to any change on the CSS

I'm sure that the link is correct, since it was working fine just before I opened Visual Code and XAMMP again

Here you can see my code:

CSS - First

HTML - Second

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
}

header{
    background: #224fb1;
    color: white;
    display: flex;
    justify-self: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1.12);
}

#iconmenu{
    margin-left: 25px;
    margin-right: 25px;
}

.title{
    display: flex;
    justify-self: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    
}


.titphp{
    font-size: large;
    font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
}

#navbar{
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1.12);
    display: inline-block;
    
}
ul{
    padding: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #444;
    list-style: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;

}

#opcnav{
    padding: 0;
    background-color: white;
    height: 25px;
    margin: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;

    

}
#opcnav:hover{
    background-color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
    transition-duration: 0.2s;
    
}
#botnav{    
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #444;
    background-color: red;
    
}
#botnav:hover{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #444;
    background-color: aqua;
    color: white;
}

#datosalumno{
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    margin-left: 300px;
    margin-right: 300px;
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: center;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1.12);
    display: inline-block;

    
}
#fotoalumno{
    margin: 10px;
    /* border-radius: 10px; */
}

#calendar{
    margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!-- 
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script> -->


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="calestilo.css">
    <title>Prueba Perfil</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="cab">
        <header>
            <div>
                    <img src="icons/hambu.png" alt="Menu" id="iconmenu"
                        height="40px"
                        
                    >
            </div>
            <div>
                <h1 id="titphp">Mi Perfil</h1>
            </div>
        </header>
    </div>

            <div id="navbar">
                <img src="icons/logo_uni_2016.png" alt="Logo Uni"
                height="50px">
                <ul id="listnav" class="nav-menu">
                    <li id="opcnav"><a id="botnav" href="http://localhost/calendario/Prac/miinfo.html" title="Mi Perfil" target="blank"><img src="icons/user.png" alt="Mi Información"
                        height="20px"> MI PERFIL</a>
                    <li id="opcnav"> <img src="icons/asistencia.png" alt="Asistencia"
                        height="20px"> ASISTENCIA
                    <li id="opcnav"><a id="botnav" href="http://localhost/calendario/Calendario.php" title="Calendario" target="blank" > <img src="icons/calendar.png" alt="Calendario"
                        height="20px"> CALENDARIO</a>
                    <li id="opcnav">En Proceso...
                    </ul>
                
            </div>


        <div class="contenedor">
            <div id="datosalumno">
                <img src="icons/user2.png" alt="Imagen Alumno"
                height="150px"
                id="fotoalumno"
                >
                <p>Nombre: El nombre irá aquí</p>
                <p>Edad: 18 años</p>
                <p>Correo: coreo123@correo.com</p>
                <p>Telefono: 123456789</p>
                <p>Turno: T1</p>


                
            </div>
        </div>


    


    
</body>
</html>
```

Did I changed something or made something different? No. I was just trying to put those block side by side instead of how it looks when you run the code, (you can see I wasn't able to do it) but then noticed that the CSS is doing nothing now.
If you need any extra detail, Ill add it without problem

Comment: Did you try to clean the cache of your browser or use it in incognito?

Comment: Cleaning Cache didn't work. Neither incognito

Comment: use some simple never used test (like `outline: 5px solid red`) to check if your style is applied at all. If it is, check devtools for if your styles are iverriden by some else style priority

Comment: This stuff also happens to me sometimes when using xampp. What fixes it for me is going to the link of the css file in the browser e.g `localhost/style.css` and hitting refresh on that page. That usually makes the css updates apparent.